# Alexa - how to display response cards on monitor

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We are using Amazon Echo Dot with Alexa.   Some of us are hearing impaired and use the Alexa app on the phone to view whatever cards are created by which ever skill we called.

But it would be very cool if could program a RaspberryPi (or whatever) to display the cards on an external monitor (wall mounte, whatever).

Is there any way to interface to my account (API?) so the cards be pushed to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can see the cards in the Alexa app which you can access online at http://alexa.amazon.com, so just open a browser in your RapsberryPi, point it to that website and login into your account. The new cards will appear at the top.

Comment: Thank you!  A rather easy solution for now!